# ADO.NET Entity Data Model - MVC - managing one-to-many relations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net-entity-data-model

Let's say that I have following situation.

I have many customers and many consultans, and each customer has attached only one consultant. So it's one-to-many relationship.

I created Edit view which display customer_name and customer_consultant_id how should I update information after post? Just UpdateModel does not work, so something more is needed. Any ideas?

Comment: You are right I will start doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those following two links seems to be completly answering my question:

[ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework, One-to-Many and Many-to-Many INSERTS](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/109/ASP.NET-MVC-Entity-Framework-One-to-Many-and-Many-to-Many-INSERTS)

[ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework, Modifying One-to-Many and Many-to-Many Relationships](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/110/ASP.NET-MVC-Entity-Framework-Modifying-One-to-Many-and-Many-to-Many-Relationships)

Answer (score 1):

To get the data from your web page to the controller, have a look at this article from Scott Hanselman:

**[ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)**

Comment: I don't find this link helpful for my case I think :(
My Customer entity doesn't have consultant_id field, it just have consultant field as another entity. This is why I don't know how to update it.